# Displaying <textarea> value as HTML

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox

I have a form with several textarea elements. User enters data and submits the form. On the next page it shows submitted text as static text - in p tags. Obviously New Line and multiple paces get ignored and everything just shows in one line. 
I can do some preprocessing like replacing New line characters with "br/" and spaces with  . but I was wondering if there is a standard solution to that either on server side (C#) or client side (javascript)

Comment: You can try to style `p` tag with `style="white-space:pre;"`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually, I ended up replacing new line symbol with [br/] and it works very well.

Answer (score 4):

Since the data is preformatted (and this isn't just a matter of presentation), the [pre element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#h-9.3.4) would be suitable (you will still need to replace `<`, `&` and friends with the appropriate entities).

Comment: Can also, but you may also want to change the `<pre>` element's default monospace font to something else by another CSS line.

Comment: If the monospaced font is a problem, you should be able to change that using CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Apply CSS [`white-space: pre;`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html) on the `<p>` element. This way any whitespace inside the element will be preserved.

Comment: Would pre-wrap take care of line breaks as well?

Comment: pre-wrap will not work in IE6&7, if you don't care, go with it.

Comment: I guess I'll have to go with "pre" tag instead then.